# View sizing after playing movie in fullscreen mode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a fairly standard navigation-based iPhone app I'm developing, where on some screens, there is a button that will play a movie using an MPMoviePlayerController in fullscreen mode.  There is a navigation bar at the top of the view.  I'm seeing some odd behaviour with the view sizing after the movie plays.  Was wondering if anybody else has seen this, and whether there is a fix.  Here is what I'm seeing:

- I hold the phone in one orientation (portrait or landscape)
- I start the movie (it plays in fullscreen mode)
- I tap the screen to hide the movie playback controls
- I rotate the phone to another orientation (portrait to landscape, or vice-versa)
- I tap the screen to bring back playback controls, and then tap the 'Done' button

At this point, the original view comes back on screen, in the new orientation.  However, the view is not sized properly to accomodate the status bar at the top of the screen.  The status bar obscures part of the navigation bar.  Rotating the phone at this point corrects the problem.

If I follow the same sequence, but without hiding the playback controls, everything works just fine, and the original view is sized properly when I dismiss the movie.

Anybody have any clue what might be causing this?

Also, this seems to be pretty easy to reproduce.  I'm using Xcode4.2 and the 5.0 SDK.  If you create a new iPhone-only project using the "Master-Detail Application" template, and make these changes, you can see the problem happen:

First, add the following code to MasterViewController.m.

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayer release];
}

- (void) playStory
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://double-apps.com/thisisatest.m4v"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Then, replace the contents of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with [self playStory]:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self playStory];
}
```

That's it, run the app, hit the 'Detail' entry in the main screen, then follow the sequence listed above.